# e+ is added with string after converting from integer

Tags: actionscript-3, type-conversion, literals

After converting integer into string , at compile time string add up with e+ 
like in trace i am getting value 90 and in swf it is showing 9.0e+

percentage function and teamxml functions are added below.

```
public function getPlayerAttack(ourTeam:Boolean=true):String{
        var attackArr:Array=[];
        var num:int;
        var total:int=0;
        var _teamXML:XML;
        if (ourTeam)
            _teamXML=getOurTeamXml();
        else
            _teamXML=getOppTeamXml();

        for each (var playerList:XML in _teamXML.player.(@gp!="0")){

            if (playerList.@name!="TEAM"){
                var attackStat:String=getStat("attack_kills",playerList);
                num = int(attackStat);
                if(num >= 10)
                {
                total += num;
                attackArr.push(num);
                }
        }   
    }
var attackPer:int = getPercent(total,attackArr.length);
        var mytext:String = String(attackPer);
        trace(typeof mytext);
        return  mytext;
    }


public function getPercent(att:int,made:int):int{
        if (made==0)
            return 0;
        return Math.round((made/att)*100);
    }


    public function getOurTeamXml():XML{
        if (homeGame)
            return xml.team.(@vh=="H")[0];
        else
            return xml.team.(@vh=="V")[0];
    }

    public function getOppTeamXml():XML{
        if (homeGame)
            return xml.team.(@vh=="V")[0];
        else
            return xml.team.(@vh=="H")[0];
    }
```

Comment: try trace(parseInt(mytext, 10)

Comment: And instead of casting from int to String, use the toString() method, i.e. var mytext:String = attackPer.toString();

Comment: Looking at `attackPer:int = getPercent(total,attackArr.length);` I wonder how that `getPercent` function works. I think it's giving you back a type **float** amount (8 bytes) but **integer** uses 4 bytes in AS3 so you get a messy value.

Comment: try this way: `var attackPer:int = int ( getPercent(total,attackArr.length) );` this will force `getPercent` result to be an integer itself... hopefully? Also please add code for `getPercent` function into your question as the solution is from there (just update/edit).

Comment: public function getPercent(att:int,made:int):int{
   if (made==0)
    return 0;
   return Math.round((made/att)*100);
  }
  
  
  public function getOurTeamXml():XML{
   if (homeGame)
    return xml.team.(@vh=="H")[0];
   else
    return xml.team.(@vh=="V")[0];
  }
  
  public function getOppTeamXml():XML{
   if (homeGame)
    return xml.team.(@vh=="V")[0];
   else
    return xml.team.(@vh=="H")[0];
  }

Comment: Okay but what are the example amounts when you run `var attackPer:int = getPercent(total,attackArr.length);`? What is value of A and B? where (A=total?,  B=attackArr.length?) because that `getPercent` function will divide B with A and multiply by 100. Does it look good if you do the math manually? `(B-value / A-value) x 100)`? Maybe switch the amounts around like:  `var attackPer:int = getPercent( attackArr.length, total );`